# PDFCreator COM interop with different versions

Tags: c#, pdf, interop

I need to connect to `PDFCreator COM interface` from C# application. For this purpose, I use VS generated Interop wrappers. But some clients have different version of PDFCreator (I have 1.2.1, some have 1.4.3) and if I use Interop generated for 1.2.1 I get exception when using the wrapper. Is there any way around this? So my app can support multiple versions of PDFCreator?

Also, I am not sure wheather PDFCreator interface actually changed. Isn´t there some lock on exact version of COM object, I could simple turn off while generating Interop libraries? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not afraid of using VB.Net instead of C#, you could try using the old VB late-binding features with the progid of PDFCreator.

The code for creating a new instance would look like this:

```
Dim myObj As Object
myObj = CreateObject("PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator")
```

Then you can call methods on `myObj` with the drawback that IntelliSense will not work and the VB.Net compiler will not raise any errors if you call a method that does not exist or if you use the wrong parameters.

Disclaimer: *I have not tested this, use it at your own risk*

Comment: So, you are basically saying that VB somehow (I will research further) can bind different versions of COM if they share common ancestors interface, and C# cannot? Why? And BTW, I have seen VB app that actually works with different PDF Creator versions, and could not understand how...

Comment: OK, so I did the research and your answer kicked me in the exact right direction! since .NET 4.0, there is support for late binding similiarly to VB! More in my answer below :)

Answer (score 8):

So, based on yms answer, I got in the right direction :)

.NET 4.0 supports late binding COM objects similiarly to VB, using `System.Type` and the magic `dynamic` keyword.

Simple example how to run PDFCreator using dynamic binding:

```
    System.Type pdfCreatorType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator");
    dynamic comPdfCreator = System.Activator.CreateInstance(pdfCreatorType);

    comPdfCreator.cStart("", true);
```

This works like a charm, and you don´t need to recompile your Interop Assemblies for each new PDFCreator version.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that I have used your solution countless times (instead of my old VB6-based approach) after you posted it. Big thanks.

Comment: How do you continue to convert a document to a PDF this way? I can't find any documentation about this.